# Rails - temporary image file storage and use options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, storage, temporary

I have been researching options for the best way to generate, store, and reference a temporary image file in a Rails production environment -- Rails 5.2 and Ruby 2.4 running on Heroku 18 stack.

The image files that this application generates will only need to be available/cached for up to a few hours.  I am not sure how cpu and i/o intensive using the /assets file system is, but I expect there is a more efficient way to generate, store, and reference an image.

Here is the current prototyped application system which generates a PNG file, stores it in /assets/images, and then references it with image_tag:

PNG file is generated and stored in a file system:

```
@barcode = Barby::Code128B.new(@variant.sku)
@blob = Barby::PngOutputter.new(@barcode).to_png

path = Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "#{@variant.sku}.png")
File.open(path, 'wb') {|f| f.write @blob }
```

PNG file is referenced in a view:

```
<%= image_tag "#{@variant.sku}.png" %>
```

Active Storage does not seem to be the correct approach since that is meant for user-uploads.  I have thought about using the Low-Level Cache for storage, but there is also the matter of easily referencing the PNG image from the view.  I am looking for some pointers and ideas about the most efficient and proper way to implement such a "temporary" file storage system for a production application.  Thank you!

Comment: Active storage looks ok for me. Its designed to work with files. And you need to save  file. Does not matter for how long. You can delete your "temporary" files later with cron or sidekiq or smtn like this.

Comment: I agree, ActiveStorage is the much better option. Especially because if you store that file on one Heroku Dyno it will not be available on other Dynos and it will disappear as soon as the Dyno restarts (what happens more often than you might think). I advise reading about [Heroku's ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

Comment: Is the [Ruby Tempfile](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/05/ruby-tempfile/) an option?